# saving & getting the values onto the page from the database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

and this is my function i used to call the query to update the values in the database:

```
function updatabout($detailsarr)
    {

        $query = "UPDATE User_details SET Marital_status='" . 
                 $detailsarr['m_status'] . "', Ethnicity='" . 
                 $detailsarr['ethinicity'] . "', Primary_language='" .            
                 $detailsarr['language'] . "', Education_level='" .
                 $detailsarr['education'] . 
                 "' WHERE User_id=".$_SESSION['uid'];
        $queryresult = mysql_query($query);
        echo mysql_error().'<br />'.$query;

}
```

here all the data are saving into my database except the "hobby" field and the value of the hobby field is showing as "undefined" in my database, as well as after clicking the save button, i'm getting the alerts & query what i used here but the values are displaying on the page only after refreshing the page...can anyone please letme know what the fault i've in this code...thanks in advance..

Comment: _Indian_ is not a language. People in India speak [hundreds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers_in_India) of languages

Comment: i dont have problem with that,i got the problem in My Hobbies field

Comment: Whoa ! Hold your horses buddy! I'm not blaming you. Just giving you the info.And i'm working on your code. Wait

Comment: okay ,thanks for information.hope you come with better solution for me

Comment: no.. i think the problem is with the `value` in `<input>` tag.. i'm not sure about it

Comment: This fragment in `hobby input` line; `value="&lt;?=$hobby?&gt;"` Shouldn't it be `value="<?php echo $hobby; ?>`, I mean an `echo` is missing there, if you want to echo a value you got previously, if any.

Comment: i tried both the ways,but not working,when i echo the query all fields are showing correctly,except the hobbies field .and it again shows as undefined

Comment: Do a `<?php var_dump($hobby); ?>` immediately before the `value="<?php echo $hobby; ?>` Does it returns `string`? And why are you using `&lt;` & `&gt;` instead of `<` & `>`? Use the literal `<` & `>`

Comment: <?php var_dump($hobby); ?> i placed this in my input field ,but i didn't got any string.still it is showing as undefined

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14442/discussion-between-davinder-and-abc123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATE** ok, Now I see you have edited and corected the mistake in your code in question. But still `<?php =$hobby ?>` doesn't make sense to me. It tells nothing to do to PHP parser. Use `echo` there, as explained in my answer.*

The only possible explanation of your problem is that the code being used in producing the `hobby` input field, specifically this fragment `value=&lt;?=$hobby?&gt;` is having problem.

Reason:
PHP processes a `&lt;?` and `<?` differently. Former is echoed as-it-is, and latter tells PHP that PHP code is started at this point, and process it. Then an un-neccesarry `=` and missing `;`.

Solution:
First of all use `value="<?php echo $hobby; ?>"` Use of full PHP tags () is always recommended over short tags () Then you need to tell PHP to echo/print the value of `$hobby` here by using `echo`. Now the output HTML should be `value="_Some_Hobby_"`

Now, if still the output HTML is `value=""` i.e. empty, then you need to check if `$hobby` actually holds a value.

As seen at http://codepad.org/dvf9bwSd in Case 3,

```
 value="&lt;?php echo $hobby; ?&gt;"
```

PHP Parser just chunks out the `&lt;php .... ?&gt;` thing as-it-is. So use literal `<` & `>`.

Now, in Case 1,

```
value="<?php echo $hobby; ?>"
<?php
var_dump($hobby);
?>
```

echoing `$hobby` variable **without** assigning it any value prints nothing. And `var_dump` also returns `NULL`

Moving on to case-2,

```
<?php
$hobby = "Coding";
?>
value="<?php echo $hobby; ?>"
<? var_dump($hobby); ?>
```

defining/assigning a value to `$hobby` and then echoing it gives us the desired result `value="Coding"` and `var_dump` also says it is a `String` of `length=6`

Comment: i did all these things dude...but don't know what's the fault in my code, i changed my code as u showed for the value, but still the value is empty, it is not showing any value there and my query shows the undefined value for the hobby field alone...

Comment: Ok, what is the output of `var_dump($user_data["hobby"]);`

Comment: see my question i've updated with the image how the error is showing in the hobby field when i echoed the query.

Comment: Yeah, it simply says `undefined` and it is because `<?=$hobby?>` is an invalid statement, but will not produce any PHP errors. First of all use `value="<?php echo $hobby?>;` instead of `value="<?=$hobby?>;` Then, write this line `var_dump($user_data["hobby"]);` in the end of your PHP code and then check the output `HTML source` and tell me what is the output of this `var_dump`?

Comment: @abc123 come over here to chat [http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14441/php-problem-of-abc123](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14441/php-problem-of-abc123) and solve this problem

Comment: hi,in the above code values are stored in the database properly,but values are displayed after refreshing the page.can any one help me to sort this problem.

Comment: @abc123 start with a new question to get more views and possible answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason why your code is not executing as expected because you didn't escape the data that is being passed on your server side script.

Try using `escape` javascript function.

Try this one:

```
"m_status=" + escape(barr[0]) + "&ethinicity=" + escape(barr[1]) + "&language=" + escape(barr[2]) +" &education=" +escape( barr[3]) + "&hobby=" + escape(barr[4])
```

You might also want to use firebug(firefox) or console(chrome) tool so that you will able to know the value that was being passed on your server side script.